# Operation could destabilize the runtime Enterprise Library 6

Tags: .net, logging, enterprise-library, verificationexception

I created a .NET 4.5 Console app to try out the Semantic Logging bits in the new Ent Lib v6.
Using the sample code from the PDF:

```
var listener2 = new ObservableEventListener();
listener2.EnableEvents( EventSourceCore.Log , EventLevel.LogAlways , Keywords.All );
SinkSubscription<SqlDatabaseSink> subscription = listener2.LogToSqlDatabase( "Demo Semantic Logging Instance" , ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mdbconn"] );
```

Running the code immediately gives the error "Operation could destabilize the runtime". Looking at the stack trace within the Exception helper from VS2012, I see

```
  at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy`1..ctor(Int32 retryCount, TimeSpan minBackoff, TimeSpan maxBackoff, TimeSpan deltaBackoff)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.Sinks.SqlDatabaseSink..ctor(String instanceName, String connectionString, String tableName, TimeSpan bufferingInterval, Int32 bufferingCount, Int32 maxBufferSize, TimeSpan onCompletedTimeout)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.SemanticLogging.SqlDatabaseLog.LogToSqlDatabase(IObservable`1 eventStream, String instanceName, String connectionString, String tableName, Nullable`1 bufferingInterval, Int32 bufferingCount, Nullable`1 onCompletedTimeout, Int32 maxBufferSize)
   at svc2.Program.LogPrep() in c:\cos\Program.cs:line 66
   at svc2.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\cos\Program.cs:line 23
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Looking at the Entlib source code, line 32 in SqlDatabaseSink.cs shows

```
 private readonly RetryPolicy retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<SqlDatabaseTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
```

Going to line 59 in RetryPolicyGeneric.cs that shows

```
 public RetryPolicy(int retryCount, TimeSpan minBackoff, TimeSpan maxBackoff, TimeSpan deltaBackoff)
            : base(new T(), retryCount, minBackoff, maxBackoff, deltaBackoff)
```

But I don't see anything like an implicit cast that could be causing the problem, that was found in other SO posts.

What did I miss? Has anyone actually seen the logging block work "out of the box"?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in core MS libraries.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2748645

That contains a patch for the problem. I burned several hours on that one. Hopefully the next person that tries this out won't have to lose the same amount of time.